# How to highlight a cell with reference to another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, highlight, conditional-formatting

Someone please help me to write an excel formula to achieve the requirement mentioned in the subject line.

I want to get a cell highlighted if the cell value is 50% or higher than the cell value to the left.

80 180

In the above case of two numbers, 180 should be highlighted.

Please help.

Regards,
Mitesh Agrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume cell `A1` has the value of 80.

Assume cell `B1` has the value of 180.

Select cell `B1`.

On the Ribbon, click `Home` -> `Conditional Formatting` -> `New Rule` -> `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

Enter the following formula:

```
=B1>=(A1+A1*0.5)
```

Click the `Format` button and then click on the `Fill` tab to select the color you want.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How can I use this for a set of values in a column. I mean using this against the columns and also reproducing it whenever needed.

Comment: Just copy the formatting downward as far as you need. You can use the Format Painter on the Home tab of the Ribbon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. I will mark your comment as the answer. Thanks again. :)